# How to get exact node based on some property

Tags: cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am creating some node and relationship as below, please ignore variables name convention:-

```
create e1={name:'sayeed', eId:1},   
p1={pId:101, is_flag1:'Y', is_flag2:'N', is_flag3:'Y'},    
p2={pId:102, is_flag1:'N', is_flag2:'N', is_flag3:'N'},   
p3={pId:103, is_flag1:'N', is_flag2:'Y', is_flag3:'N'},  
p1<-[:HAS_REL]-e1, p2<-[:HAS_REL]-e1, p3<-[:HAS_REL]-e1;
```

and searching node from this query:

```
start e = node:node_auto_index('name:sayeed')  
match e-[:HOLD]-p
where p.is_flag2='N'  
return distinct e;
```

The above query gets the entity "e" but in my case it should not get. Below is the detailed description.

I want to get entity which has ":HAS_REL" relationship and all "is_flag2" value should be "N"
if any one of "is_flag2" is "Y" I should not get the entity.Please Let me know
how can I write the cypher query.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this query:

```
START e = node:node_auto_index('name:sayeed') 
MATCH e-[:HAS_REL]-p 
WHERE p.is_flag2='N' 
RETURN DISTINCT e;
```

You were using the incorrect relationship lookup in your match clause. I hope this helps.